# how to enable the spi to connect mcp251x with yocto?

Tags: yocto, spi, can-bus

I am new to yocto and i have generated a linux image for my raspberrypi-cm3 and i want to connect an mcp2515 to my cm3 to test the can driver.

the mcp251x.ko , can_dev.ko , spidev.ko spi_bcm2835.ko and spi_2835aux.ko modules are loaded and when i write ' dmesg | grep can' i get messages that mcp251x is finely there but when i write ' dmesg | grep spi' nothing shows up.

also in my 'config.txt' file the spi is set to 'off' by default.

Can someone please  help me to enable the spi so i can test the mcp251x of the can?

Comment: Did you enable SPI controller & protocol drivers using kernel menuconfig ? `CONFIG_SPI` `CONFIG_SPI_MASTER`

Answer (score 0):

Open .dts file in your kernel and enable `spi` and set `STATUS="okay"`
and write platform data for spidev

```
&spi0 {
       pinctrl-names = "default";
       pinctrl-0 = <&spi0_pins_a>,
                   <&spi0_cs0_pins_a>;
       status = "okay";

       spidev@0x00 {
               compatible = "spidev";
               spi-max-frequency = <1200000>;
               reg = <0>;
       };
```

and open `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`. then enable `spidev` present in devicer/drivers.